# How to add columns to ListMember table in Microsoft CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

For the n:m list membership, Microsoft CRM uses an intersect table called `ListMember`. With a solution/plugin I need to attach new columns to this table. I know that I could create a new entity with this and keep it in sync with `ListMember`, i.e. creating one whenever a member is added to a list and modifying it when a member is moved to a different list, etc. But that's quite a lot of overhead I think.

Is there a way to attach new fields to to the `ListMember` entity in CRM 2011?

[image: Entities envolved in lists]

<sub>Source: [How to integrate with Dynamics CRM Marketing Lists with a plug-in](http://www.koorb.co.nz/highlights-and-updates/how-to-integrate-with-dynamics-crm-marketing-lists-with-a-plug-in/)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have additional fields for a many-to-many relationship you must create a manual relationship (by creating an intermediate entity.) This is not an oversight, it is in the Dynamics CRM training material.

As for Marketing Lists, you shouldn't be trying to add more information to this relationship - it is a flaw in the solution design/architecture.

You wouldn't need to keep anything in sync. Use Dynamic Marketing Lists and they will be kept in sync. The only purpose of a Marketing List is to create the activities for a Campaign/Quick Campaign. If Marketing List membership is being used for another purpose that is a solution design issue that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We use marketing lists for invitations to events and the idea is to store invitation details like companions and diet restrictions with the list membership. Do you have an idea how to store this information in a better way?

Comment: Sure, create a custom entity to the hold the information. Then create a dynamics marketing list which filters the relevant records based on their relationship to the custom entity.